# How to find speed and acceleration before and after the loss of vehicle parts?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws

Suppose that we have a vehicle of mass $M$ such that $$M=\sum_{i=1}^Nm_i$$ If the total sum of lost objects is $M'=m_1+m_2+\cdots +m_i$ with $i<N$ during a races, unnecessary objects that impede the ride, how can I physically prove with formulas that the velocity and the acceleration increases?

Comment: If a part you lost is required for the engine or wheel to to function then you aren't going any faster. If there was no driving force to begin then your speed won't change just because you lost some mass. Your scenario is under specified.l

Comment: I do not understand why you copied a comment in the original question. I find it confusing. The original question was clearer.

Comment: @GiorgioP The change is due to the fact that my English is unclear and I put the same comment as the user. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming linear motion and constant applied force and that when the parts fall off, they just detach and continue with their velocity until they hit the ground, use conservation of momentum and Newton's 2nd Law applied to before and after the parts fall off to see the following ratios:

$$v_f = \frac{M}{M-M'} v_i$$
$$a_f = \frac{M}{M-M'} a_i$$

Since $\frac{M}{M-M'} > 1$, velocity and acceleration both increase. Does this answer your question?

Comment: As Have you tried the v_F and a_F. Can you put any details. Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean? $v_f$ is the velocity of the vehicle after the parts fall off. $a_f$ is the acceleration of the vehicle due to the same force after the parts fall off.

Comment: I would like to know kindly how you found the formulas you wrote down.